# Flutter path_provider and connectivity_plus version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart, package, pubspec

I can't install Flutter's connectivity package due to a version conflicting issue with the path_provider package. I tried exchanging different versions of both packages but no luck. Can anyone please guide me on how to fix this issue here?

Error on Log :

```
   Because connectivity_plus >=1.0.2 depends on connectivity_plus_platform_interface ^1.0.2 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, connectivity_plus >=1.0.2 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0.
    And because path_provider >=1.6.4 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, connectivity_plus >=1.0.2 is incompatible with path_provider >=1.6.4 <2.0.0-nullsafety.
    So, because cliffjumper depends on both path_provider ^1.6.11 and connectivity_plus ^1.0.5, version solving failed.
    pub get failed (1; So, because cliffjumper depends on both path_provider ^1.6.11 and connectivity_plus ^1.0.5, version solving failed.)
```

In pubspec.yaml file :

```
enter code version: 1.0.0+1
    
    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
    
    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
    
    
      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
      rxdart: ^0.26.0
      sqflite: ^1.3.1
      path_provider: ^1.6.11
      http: ^0.12.1
      #flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
      #google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
      flutter_blue: ^0.8.0
      google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.5
      geolocator: ^6.1.6
      device_info: ^2.0.0
      shared_preferences: ^0.5.10
      crypto: ^3.0.1
      uuid: ^3.0.4
      latlong: ^0.6.1
      geocoder: ^0.2.1
      us_states: ^1.0.3
      package_info: ^0.4.3+2
      weather: ^1.2.4
      connectivity_plus: ^1.0.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to update all the plugins to their latest version or simply use 'any' keyword instead of version code

Comment: No, it's not working. Tried in both way, the package installed but unfortunately getting this error while importing this package - "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart'."

Comment: try  to run flutter clean and rebuild the application

Comment: Your welcome give a Tick if this solution is correct.